# Setting a variables to contain a range of numbers in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a case statement for a dialog menu, and want it to refer to multiple numbers (one to nine), if any number from one to nine is selected.

How do I make a word have multiple values? Now

```
: ${EXAMPLE=9}
```

but how would I make it equal multiple numbers?

I've tried so far:

```
: ${EXAMPLE=1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

: ${EXAMPLE=1-9}

: ${EXAMPLE=1 && 2 && 3}
```

Context:

I made a menu dialog that lists all files in a certain area, and want to make a case such as

```
case $example in
        **1)**  # but not just 1, it should be 1-9

   echo "blah blah" ;;

esac
```

Comment: You mean something like `case "$x" in [1-9])`?

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. Can you give us an example ? or explain how you'd wanna use that ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yeah something that will refer to many numbers in 1 case rather than repeating the same thing multiple times with each new number as a case. i edited my post if you wana look at the bottom of it i added a example you might see better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's couple things you can do:

- use range `[1-9]`
- use `|` to create list of "or" values
- use wildcard:

Example:

```
bash-4.3$ var=25
bash-4.3$ case $var in 
> [1-9]) echo "1 to 9";; 
> 25|35|45) echo "25 or 25 or 45" ;;
> 5*) echo "starting with 5";;
> esac
25 or 25 or 45
```

Case is mostly for patterns, so if you want to have arithmetic evaluation, you'd better use if statement with `[`  although you can do something like `[1-5][0-9][0-9]) echo "100 to 599" ;;` to see if item is within range 100 to 599 (i.e., var>=100 && var<=599) . See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65310/85039) for more info on arithmetic in bash's case statement.

Comment: So when I state it then I would do something like: array=[1-9]. (Edit) nevermjnd I just re-read your reply and it makes more sense. Thanks!